# SharePoint Takes 15 Seconds to Load Page

Tags: performance, wcf

I've got a problem with my SharePoint 2010 farm and I can't think where to start.  Bizzarly, this is happening in multiple completly seperate environments (DEV/TEST/PREPROD/PROD).

Every so often (apparently randomly, about 10 to 50 minutes apart), a page will randomly go from loading in under a second to taking 15+ seconds.

This happens totally randomly, even with a warmup script and multiple users browsing all day.

I've gone through my logs and found that the following entries correspond to the slow loading pages.

```
11/17/2011 16:02:21.15  w3wp.exe (0x1600)                           0x1410  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfOperation:http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/taxonomy/soap/IDataAccessReadOnly/GetChanges). Execution Time=15026.2985938157  
11/17/2011 16:02:21.15  w3wp.exe (0x1600)                           0x1410  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (Proxy Channel call for Enterprise Metadata Service). Execution Time=15027.1171336022    
11/17/2011 16:02:21.18  w3wp.exe (0x0510)                           0x0D08  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfOperation:http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/taxonomy/soap/IDataAccessReadOnly/GetChanges). Execution Time=15040.257909874   
11/17/2011 16:02:21.18  w3wp.exe (0x0510)                           0x0D08  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (Proxy Channel call for Enterprise Metadata Service). Execution Time=15040.9197258311
```

At the time of freeze the CPU on the SharePoint WFE and APP servers is fine, CPU and disk IO on the SQL server are fine and everything looks 'normal'.

Does anybody know what could be causing this strange behaviour?  I've been looking at scheduled jobs and can't see anything that corresponds to the time of the delays.

Would love suggestions of things that could be causing this!  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you are consuming a Managed Metadata Service(to consume shared content types or metadata) which takes time.

Comment: MMS taking 15 secs to fetch data is not normal. I'd check the event logs to see if the app pool for it keeps falling over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We were having this same issue, though with a different service, search instead of managed metadata. The load frequently took 15 seconds. This KB article had the fix for us: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2625048 .

SharePoint 2010 uses SSL to encrypt intra-farm communication. It should work invisibly, but under the right conditions, it can cause problems, resulting in these 15 second timeouts. The fix is to export SharePoint's SSL cert through PowerShell, then explicitly add it to the server's Trusted Root Authentication Provider store through the MMC's Certificate snap-in. The KB article has the steps.

Comment: L-Train8 you are spot on - this was the cause all along.  I followed the steps in the KB you proivded and the problem, which has been plaguing me for months every single day, stopped instantly.   On two seperate sites, too.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if the application pool from IIS has been reset when the page get 15+ seconds to load?

Comment: Hmm, checked the app pool and no evidence of any recycles. Thanks for suggestions - still digging around the logs.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some points which I could think of, which might help you,

1. It may depend on your farm configuration. If your farm is a stand alone server or the index server is hosted on the same web front end servers, this might occur when crawling occurs parallely.
2. Check for any timer jobs or user profile synchronization which might be running parallely.
3. Check for the custom web parts or custom codes that you have created on these pages which could have performance issues.
4. Check for Disk spaces, Database sizes or database performances that might have affected recently.

Comment: Thanks Deepu - I'm still not sure what's going on. I'll spend some more time reviewing timer jobs, web parts and other bits. Thanks all for the suggestions - I tried to upvote you but don't have enough points :(

Comment: thats ok Ben, let us know how the issue gets solved. All the best.